# getting perticular listbox selected value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have html listbox as, which has same name but different id

```
<select name="dept"  id="vrow" >
                        <option selected="selected" > - Select Department- </option>
                        <option value="GEN">computer </option>
                        <option value="SC">mac </option>
                        <option value="ST">civ </option>
                        <option value="OBC">ele </option>
                      </select>
```

i had atteched it to each row fetched from database,
how can i get ID if i change perticular listbox value.

Comment: you use ajax function for get results from server database

Answer (score 1):

If you need id then use:

```
document.getElementById('vrow').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   if (e.target.name==='dept') {
     alert(e.target.id);
   }
})
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qvzvgtbr/)

If you need value then use:

```
document.getElementById('vrow').addEventListener('change', function(e){
   if (e.target.name==='dept') {
       alert(e.target.value);
   }
})
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qvzvgtbr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener on `change` event to parent node of all `<select>` elements it can `ul` if they are in list or even `body`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementByTagName('UL').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.name==='dept') {
      //In this case you have got element that you need and its id 
      //e.target.id
      alert(e.target.id);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Will you please tell me what change i have to make in html listbox coding?

Comment: Insert that code before you close 'body' tag (</body>).

Answer (score 0):

You Write Javascript Function or Jquery function

like this

```
<select onchange="dept(this.value)" name="dept"  id="vrow" >
<option selected="selected" > - Select Department- </option>
<option value="GEN">computer </option>
<option value="SC">mac </option>
<option value="ST">civ </option>
<option value="OBC">ele </option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dept(id){
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax.php',
data: { id: id} ,
success: function (response) {
try{
alert(response);
}
catch(e){
alert("Error"+e);
}
},
error: function (e) {
alert("error"+e); or alert("error"+JSON.stringify(e));
}
});
}
</script>
```

Ajax.php